# Dolphin is not showing the image dimensions metadata when previewing images on Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin, photo-management, previews

The Dolphin file manager is not showing the dimensions metadata when hovering over the images and previewing them. It used to show them in the past.

**How do I show the image dimensions metadata when hovering over the image?**

---

At the moment, when hovering over any image, I am getting the following basic information without the dimensions:

[image]

**Note 1:** Using the right-click button is not helping at all. I am still not able to see any option that would bring up the dimensions.

**Note 2:** Going to the properties window is also not helping. I still can't see the dimensions in that area.

---

**My System Information:**

- **Dolphin:** 16.04.3
- **KDE:** 5.28.0
- **Qt:** 5.6.1
- **Kubuntu OS:** 16.10
- **Kernel:** 4.8.0-37-generic
- **PhotoQt Image Viewer:** v1.5.1

---

**Update:** Updating my system to Kubuntu 17.04 and enabling the backports PPA to get the latest versions did not help in solving the problem.

---

Any guides, links, comments, terminal commands, or answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that there is an old bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332065. Although its status says "fixed", I am running into this problem on recent versions of KDE (it is back in Kubuntu 17.10). Following some instructions in https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332065#c30 and disabling file indexing "fixes" the problem. I have tried it and it indeed works.

The bug's comment mentioned above also says that if file indexing is enabled, deleting or renaming `~/.local/share/baloo/`, thus forcing the index to be created again may also solve it, but for me it again stopped showing the metadata after restarting the system. Disabling file indexing altogether appears to be a more "permanent" solution. It can also be done in the GUI by opening System Settings, Search, then turning off the 'Enable File Search' option. Disabling file search/indexing will, of course, stop showing files in search results across Plasma desktop (Dolphin's own Find option will still keep working).

Comment: This is still (Kubuntu 19.04) an issue and your post the solution.

Comment: This is still (Kubuntu 18.04) an issue (in 2021).

Answer (score 1):

Although I have tried this on Kubuntu 16.10 in the past with no fruitful results, it seems to be working now on Kubuntu 17.04.

**Step 1:** Launch your terminal.
**Step 2:** Disable the Baloo by typing the command below:

```
balooctl disable
```

**Step 3:** Update, then start your system. You should be able to see the missing metadata now.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that ID3 Version 2 tags are missing. You can add ID3 version 2 tags with KID3 for example:

```
sudo apt install kid3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I already have the latest version of kid3 installed (3.4.4-1). I am currently using Kubuntu 17.04 with Kubuntu backports enabled but the issue is still present and valid without finding any way to solve it.